# Generating optimal list of Java imports with Xtext

Tags: java, import, xtext

Is there a way to collect a list of necessary imports while Xtext generates Java code and then insert this list at the top *after* processing the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We do that in the domain model example. You can import the example into your workspace using the wizard.

Comment: I imported the project with "new -> xtext -> examples -> domain model example" but there is no example model in any of the three projects nor any code that does anything with the model (except for the editors). I'm using Xtext 1.0.1

Comment: I tried the same with Xtext 2.0M5 (just in case you meant that version) but I couldn't get the example to compile. It seems that the example code wasn't updated for M5.

Comment: I meant Xtext 1.0.*. There are no example models but the code for the import normalization is located in the *.generator package.

Comment: Ah. That's not part of the "generation" but of the "code formatter" step, then?